# Is there any way to read from context only after all of the writes are done in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to implement a queue data structure on the hyperledger fabric. For this purpose i need some kind of blocking write-read semantics( after removement of an element from the queue it should be unreachable from the context to any node).

I didn't found any mechanisms for this thing yet.

Here's what i have:

```
item.IsRemoved = true
updatedItemAsBytes, _ := json.Marshal(item)
ctx.GetStub().PutState(queryResponse.Key, updatedItemAsBytes)
bytes, _ := ctx.GetStub().GetState(queryResponse.Key) 
element := new(QueueItem)
_ = json.Unmarshal(bytes, element)
```

And then element.IsRemoved still false(default value). As far as i understand, it's because transactions are not blocking and new value will be available only after nodes will confirm that it's correct.

How to handle this case? Are there any API methods? Do i need to change transaction confirmation rules to single(current) node? Or what's the right way to do it in hyperledger?

Comment: I do not understand well your use case but, of course, the world state (the DB) only changes after the block that contains the transaction has been committed. This is step 6 in https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/txflow.html. Until that, your endorser peers are only simulating the transaction execution against the DB as it was updated after the last valid block.

Comment: @kekomal, thank you for the quick answer. the question is how to READ only after transaction completes? is there any methods in API to do this? or what's the right way to achieve it?

Comment: You can subscribe to an event **in your client** (not in your chaincode). You can subscribe to the transaction commit built-in event or launch your custom event (in your chaincode). https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/master/tutorial-transaction-commit-events.html https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/peer_event_services.html

Comment: @kekomal, the thing is i can't rely on clients(they may be written in a wrong way). is there any technique to organize simple FIFO queue using chaincode? some mechanism for simple removement(marking) of already polled element that will block all of the consumers till the actual write to world state ends?

Comment: But the thing is that the transaction cannot wait for itself to be committed. It makes no sense, as the transaction is not going to be committed until it finish its execution (in all the required endorser peers). Maybe you can rely on the update of a single common document for each queue to take approach of Fabric's inconcurrency, but then you could only perform one queue update per block (so it may be slow) and it is a weird "solution". About Fabric's inconcurrency: https://medium.com/wearetheledger/hyperledger-fabric-concurrency-really-eccd901e4040.

Comment: What I mean is that, if you update (for instance, the revision number of) one (the same) LevelDB/CouchDB element each time you operate over the queue, if you make 2 or more queue operations in the same block, you are going to receive a `MVCC_READ_ERROR` for each transaction (except the first one), and maybe you can take approach of that. But it is weird and slow. I wouldn't take that approach, but it is what I can think of.